# My discord bot stopped working after I added new block

Tags: python, discord.py

I started making discord bot for my server but when i added new part of code, bot suddenly stopped reacting to everything except the new part of code. I am just starting with coding in python so I would really appreciate help. Here is the code, hope it helps.
Thanks in advance.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@client.event
# event po spusteni
async def on_ready():
    notificationChannel = client.get_channel(715183011913662485)
    await notificationChannel.send("HALLO!")

    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online,
                                 activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="Tunelcraft"))



@client.command(name="rock", pass_context = True)
async def rock(context, member: discord.Member):
    rock = context.guild.get_role(788874909211295754)

    await member.add_roles(rock)
    await context.message.channel.send(f"User {member} has been awarded with rock.")


@client.command(name="version")
async def version(context):
    version = discord.Embed(title="TEAM JANO version", color=0x19b2f2)
    version.add_field(name="Version of code:", value="Alpha 1.2")
    version.add_field(name="Release date", value="16.12.2020")
    version.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/781865362383044608/789055594983850014/banana.jpg")
    version.set_footer(text="Made by Nicitel007")

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=version)


@client.command(name="helpjoke")
async def helpjoke(context):
    helpjoke = discord.Embed(title="Joke commands", color=0x19b2f2)
    helpjoke.add_field(name="", value="barjoke")
    helpjoke.set_footer(text="Made by Nicitel007")

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=helpjoke)




@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    if message.content == "!barjoke":
        list = ["What does skeleton says when he walks into bar? One beer and sponge please.", "What does horse says whem it walks into bar? Pfffft!"]
        await channel.send(random.choice(list))









client.run("bot token here")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `client.process_commands` at the end of the `on_message` event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    if message.content == "!barjoke":
        list = ["What does skeleton says when he walks into bar? One beer and sponge please.", "What does horse says whem it walks into bar? Pfffft!"]
        await channel.send(random.choice(list))

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Also, why don't you put it in a command?

Comment: Instead of thanking simply [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: oh sorry this is my first time using stack overflow